# Are there any services/sites/organizations/clubs at which video games can be traded?

Tags: video-games, used-goods, cost-cutting

My family plays a lot of video games (PS3 and Nintendo DSi) - are there cheaper alternatives to buying the games new?  Library service of sorts?  Wishful thinking?

Comment: Assuming that you are looking at the legally available options.

Comment: Yes :) I`m too legit to quit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There certainly are. One that is gaining some steam is http://www.swaptree.com/, they offer swapping of books, dvds, music, and games.

Answer (score 2):

[EBGames](http://www.ebgames.com/)/[Gamestop](http://www.gamestop.ca/) does have a buy and trade program.  Depending on age of the game, not all titles are supported but it is a good way to recycle older games and try out newer ones without breaking the bank.